# Is there something like the Select-Control in HTML but in Windows Forms?

Tags: html, winforms, drop-down-menu, controls, dropdown

I'm searching for the dropdown-menu where you can choose one of a few options in Windows Forms. I know it exists in HTML, but I haven't found it in Windows Forms yet.

The HTML-code for the Control looks like this:

```
<select name="List">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [MenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menustrip) Class -- [ToolStripMenuItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem) -- [ContextMenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip) Class -- [ToolStripComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripcombobox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **ComboBox** control.

Here is a link to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=netframework-4.0).

And one more with a detailed description of usage: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/combobox-in-C-Sharp/

Regards,

Todor